# Trying to connect two Pi 4s via respective ethernet ports

Tags: networking, ethernet, raspberry-pi

I have two Raspberry Pi 4s that each have a Wifi connection to the router. I would like to connect them together via ethernet as well (no router between them - direct eth0 to eth0), to be able to transmit files back and forth quickly. I've tried connecting the Pi to a mac directly, and this works just fine - I can talk to the Pi both via mac's ethernet port and Wifi. However, I can't seem to do this Pi to Pi - neither's ethernet adapter has an IP - wifi adapters do. Any suggestions?

Update - here's the ifconfig, showing that IP4 is not present. The other adapter shows similar information:

```
end0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::47cd:8b1d:ad12:7912  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:3a:dd:9e:f9:9f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 2416 (2.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Can you explain "don't see each other" in more detail? Do they fail to establish the Ethernet link (according to `ip link` or `ethtool eth0`), or do they fail to send packets to each other's IP address (according to `ping`), or do they fail to recognize each other's hostnames (`my-pi.local`) or do they fail to show each other in the file manager or what?

Comment: What is the `ifconfig` on each? Same subnet, different IP addresses, appropriate subnet mask?

Comment: Do any of them provide dhcp or other ways of auto assigning IP addresses? If not then you may need to install such a service, or manually set static IP addresses for the both of them. To make things less confusing you should use a different IP range/subnet than the one used by your existing LAN if you go with static configs.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I guess I should clarify that neither seems to have a v4 IP on eth0. Which makes it impossible to connect to either

Comment: @Transistor neither has an IP on eth0. The wireless adapters both have IPs on the same subnet

Comment: I updated description to include ifconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question - looks like I needed to enable connection sharing to be able to interconnect them - I followed the steps outlined in this [SO answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/144824/bridging-wifi-to-ethernet-with-networkmanager) (coincidentally, also self-answered).

Answer (score 0):

> that neither seems to have a v4 IP on eth0. Which makes it impossible to connect to either

You need to manually configure those. Pick any subnet that doesn't conflict with your existing networks (a /30 is enough, a /24 will also work fine) and use `ip addr add` (or the old `ifconfig`) to set up both interfaces with IP addresses from that subnet.

For IPv4 addresses to appear automatically, there would need to be a DHCP server on the network (e.g. Dnsmasq running on one Pi). For two devices it's a waste of time setting up one (as the Pi running the server would need manual IP configuration anyway).

Alternatively, you can run avahi-autoipd on both Pi's to have 169.254.x.x addresses show up.